# Convert a column in a dataframe from type string to tuple

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a dataframe 'data' which has a column 'city' that appears to be a tuple. However, when I try to access its element, it comes out to be in string. As shown below:

```
data.city[0]
```

The output is:

```
"(0, ['New York', 'Delhi', 'Bangkok'])"
```

Apparently, all the items are in string format.

I want the output as follows:

```
(0, ['New York', 'Delhi', 'Bangkok'])
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval`

```
import ast
x = ast.literal_eval("(0, ['New York', 'Delhi', 'Bangkok'])")
print(x)
print(type(x))
```

Output:

```
(0, ['New York', 'Delhi', 'Bangkok'])
<class 'tuple'>
```

In your case, you can use:

```
data.city = data.city.apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Comment: Hi, I want to do the same thing too. Is there any method that I can convert string to tuple in the whole dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

Use `ast.literal_eval`. Although it can throw exceptions if you have an empty string. So, wrapping that in a `str` function should be prudent:

```
from ast import literal_eval
df['city'] = df.city.apply(lambda x: literal_eval(str(x)))
```

Comment: Hi, I want to do the same thing too. Is there any method that I can convert string to tuple in the whole dataframe?